# How to copy the result from the last search across a folder without copying results from previous searches in Notepad++?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

I performed a search across a folder in Notepad++. How to copy the results from the search without copying the results from the previous searches?

I use  the latest version of Notepad++   with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: How did you do the search? If I use <ctrl>+h> then "Find in Files" I only get the results from the latest search.